# Does adding water to drinks reduce their glycemic index?

Tags: blood-sugar

I have noticed the degree of sweetness of the food corresponds with the likelihood to get acne.

Whereas, diluting the flavor reduces the likelihood even if total calorie intake is same.

Is there science to support this?

Comment: Welcome to HealthSE! Please increase how your headline corresponds to your body text. GI, taste and flavours don't seem to match very well; and how do pimples get into the picture? Maybe if you share a bit of your previous research on this can clarify what you are asking. This might also help: [How to ask](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Ditto to @LangLangC's comment. I'm not sure if you're asking about GI or acne.

Comment: You can edit your post by clicking the "edit" link at the bottom of your post.

Answer (score 3):

**Question:** Does reducing the sweetness of a drink by diluting it with water reduces the likelihood of acne?

**Short answer:** Not necessary.

I am not aware of any study that would show an association between the mere *sweetness* of a food and the risk of acne.

There is some evidence that **low-glycemic load diet** may help reduce acne ([Cochrane](http://www.cochrane.org/CD009436/SKIN_complementary-therapies-acne-vulgaris), [PubMed Central](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4106357/)).

Glycemic load = glycemic index x grams of carbohydrates in the food. Glycemic index is an estimation of the effect of a food on the blood glucose level after its ingestion.

Examples of **high-glycemic index foods** (GI >70) are some sweet beverages, cornflakes, instant oatmeal, white rice, potatoes, white bread, pasta, biscuits and other baked goods made from white flour and little fiber ([Harvard](https://www.health.harvard.edu/diseases-and-conditions/glycemic-index-and-glycemic-load-for-100-foods)).

As you can see, high-glycemic foods are not necessary sweet.

Diluting "the sweetness" of a food or beverage may not reduce its glycemic index. The [Glycemicindex.com](http://www.glycemicindex.com/faqsList.php) gives this example (but no link to any study):

> A more dilute solution, say 25 grams fructose in 500 mL water will
>   have a **higher** GI than 25 grams fructose in 250 mL.

Such estimation sounds counterintuitive, but it makes sense, because a beverage with 5% sugar (25 g fructose in 500 mL water) usually empties from the stomach faster than a beverage with 10% sugar (25 g sugar in 250 mL water) ([Nutrition and Metabolism](https://nutritionandmetabolism.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1743-7075-6-9)). So, the diluted beverage passes from the stomach into the intestine faster, which results in faster glucose absorption and thus in higher GI.

To decrease the glycemic load of the meals, you can decrease the amount of high glycemic index foods, for example, eating whole-grain bread (high in fiber) instead of white flour products (low in fiber).

Comment: I edited the answer.

Comment: +1 Nailed it with the gastric emptying and fiber.  And good to see you @Jan!  Have you visited Meta recently? There's an important discussion going on about retaining experts -  https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/q/798/6776

Answer (score 1):

Glycemic index (GI) helps to rates carbohydrate-containing foods (or drinks) by how much they boost blood sugar (blood glucose).
Although GI offers useful information that can help you choose foods that have kinder, gentler effects on blood sugar, it is not a perfect guide for choosing a healthy diet. Why ? According to According to [Patrick J. Skerrett, Former Executive Editor, Harvard Health](https://www.health.harvard.edu/blog/use-glycemic-index-to-help-control-blood-sugar-201208135154),

> Some foods, like carrot and watermelon, have a high glycemic index, but a serving contains so little carbohydrate that the effect on blood sugar is small. Others, like sugary soda, have a moderate glycemic index because they contain a fair amount of fructose, which has relatively little effect on blood sugar. But they also pack plenty of glucose, which does boost blood sugar.

Secondly, he suggested that the GI of a particular drink (or food) can also be influenced by what it is eaten with.

> Olive oil or something acidic, like vinegar or lemon juice, can slow the conversion of starch to sugar, and so lower the glycemic index.

Now over to the exact matter:

Does adding water to drinks reduce their glycemic index?

Indirectly? Arguably YES since this will reduce insulin resistance and help a person reduce their hunger/thirst (thus reducing consumption).  According to [Eliot LeBow -Diabetes on Sharecare.com](https://www.sharecare.com/health/diabetes/drinking-water-blood-sugar)

> proper hydration seems to reduce one's blood sugars by decreasing insulin resistance while at the same time reduces a person's need to take more 
>   drinks or food during the day. Also, enough water will help remove the 
>   excess sugar and ketones out of your system.

Comment: This is a really good answer, but it lacks any supporting citations and site rules require it. Could you add one or two to support your major assertions of fact?

Comment: @CareyGregory thanks. Let me update the references on the post

Comment: Why is this post Community Wiki?

Comment: Please enlighten me is I got it wrong, I read you can make a post wiki so that anyone can update.

Comment: The part of the last quote: "Also, enough water will help remove the excess sugar and ketones out of your system." is not true. Water does not remove sugar or ketones from the body. Also, the post does not provide any evidence about the association between hydration and acne.